# vue js application in ssr mode cache in browser and not calling Api from backend

Tags: nginx, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a vuejs frontend app in ssr mode and run with pm2 . I reverse proxy this app on nginx on main domain
for the first time when application load in browser its cached and in second time site load from cache and non off apies not call .
when I access the application from original port everything works and have no problem
but when its reverse with proxy this problem accur.

there is no cdn active on the domain.

this is my nginx config file:

```
server {

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  server_name example.com;

location ~ ^/(robots.txt) {
        root /srv/www/example;
    }
location ~ ^/(sitemap.xml) {
        root /srv/www/example;
    }




    location / {

        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5001;
    }
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


  server_name example.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

I try to add some header like below to nginx config file but it dose not work

`proxy_cache off; proxy_set_header Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"; proxy_set_header Pragma "no-cache"; proxy_set_header Expires "0";`